# VBA code stops execution without error after hiding rows

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having quite the struggle with some code that used to work just fine. In one of my subs, I hide a bunch of rows (1599 to be exact), then unhide the ones I need, usually around 200. Check out the code:

```
Private Sub HideUnneededRows(numberToShow As Integer)
Dim thisSheet As Worksheet
Dim allHideableRows As String, rowsToShow As String
Dim firstRow As Integer
Dim secondRow As Integer
Dim lastRow As Integer
Dim lastRowToShow As Integer

    Set thisSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

    firstRow = thisSheet.Range("mass1").row
    secondRow = firstRow + 1
    lastRow = firstRow - 1 + maxNumberOfRows
    lastRowToShow = firstRow - 1 + numberToShow '//numberToShow is usually 200

    '//THIS NEXT LINE RUNS, BUT STOPS EXECUTING AFTER THE ACTION IS PERFORMED
    Range("A" + CStr(secondRow) + ":A" + CStr(lastRow)).EntireRow.Hidden = True 
    Range("A" + CStr(secondRow) + ":A" + CStr(lastRowToShow)).EntireRow.Hidden = False

End Sub
```

All is well and good until the code hides the rows (first of the "Range("A" +....).Hidden" lines). It performs the hide action just fine, but then doesn't reach the next line of code, which would be to un-hide a different set of rows. 
Things I've tried:

- Hard-coding the range string (i.e. `Range("A25:A1623")` instead of `Range("A" + CStr(secondRow) + ":A" + ....)`)
- Performing these two hide actions through the `Rows` object (i.e. `Rows("25:1623").Hidden = True`)
- Extracting those two hide lines into their own `button_click` event in a new module to see if it was something about the module it was currently in

All of these have yielded the exact same result - the code stops all execution after the 1599 rows are hidden.

Help?!

Comment: I used your code to hide over 26,000 rows and it worked fine. I did notice that sheet(s) were recalculated (at least partially because I have some of my own UDFs marked as `Volatile`). Maybe try disabling events and screen updates prior to the hide (and re-enable of course).

Comment: @PeterT Thank you for your comments. The code can be further modified and optimized. Hopefully, the core issue is resolved pertinent to the PO question. Best regards,

Comment: @PeterT YOU WIN!! Turning off events didn't fix it, but turning off `ScreenUpdating` fixed the problem. Why did that work? Why would a lot of recalculations (I did have approx 4800 cells with conditional formatting) cause the code to die?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @PeterT, the solution to my problem was to turn off screen updating before running the code, then turning it back on after the code finished running. The new code is as such:

```
Private Sub HideUnneededRows(numberToShow As Integer)
Dim thisSheet As Worksheet
Dim firstRow As Integer
Dim secondRow As Integer
Dim lastRow As Integer
Dim lastRowToShow As Integer

    Set thisSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

    firstRow = thisSheet.Range("mass1").row
    secondRow = firstRow + 1
    lastRow = firstRow - 1 + maxNumberOfRows
    lastRowToShow = firstRow - 1 + numberToShow '//numberToShow is usually 200

    '//Turn off ScreenUpdating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    '//THIS NEXT LINE WAS GIVING ME TROUBLES
    Range("A" + CStr(secondRow) + ":A" + CStr(lastRow)).EntireRow.Hidden = True 
    Range("A" + CStr(secondRow) + ":A" + CStr(lastRowToShow)).EntireRow.Hidden = False
    '//Turn ScreenUpdating back on
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: OMG! The ScreenUpdate turn of solved everything for me!!

Answer (score 1):

The following code snippets used for debugging purpose works just fine (hide/unhide rows)

```
Private Sub HideUnneededRows()
Dim thisSheet As Worksheet
Dim allHideableRows As String, rowsToShow As String
Dim firstRow As Integer
Dim secondRow As Integer
Dim lastRow As Integer
Dim lastRowToShow As Integer

'for debugging purpose
numberToShow = 200
maxNumberOfRows = 300
'--------------------

    Set thisSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

    'firstRow = thisSheet.Range("mass1").Row
    ' for debugging purpose
    firstRow = 1
    secondRow = firstRow + 1
    lastRow = firstRow - 1 + maxNumberOfRows
    lastRowToShow = firstRow - 1 + numberToShow '//numberToShow is usually 200

    '//THIS NEXT LINE RUNS, BUT STOPS EXECUTING AFTER THE ACTION IS PERFORMED
    Range("A" + CStr(secondRow) + ":A" + CStr(lastRow)).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Range("A" + CStr(secondRow) + ":A" + CStr(lastRowToShow)).EntireRow.Hidden = False

End Sub
```

Check all your "magic numbers" like `maxNumberOfRows` variable (set to 300 for debugging purpose: where it comes from/declared?) and the `firstRow` from that "mysterious" Range "mass1".

***Note***: in VBA code, the strings concatenation is typically done with ampersand "`&`", but this syntax will work fine as well:

```
Range("A" + CStr(secondRow) + ":A" + CStr(lastRow))
```

Hope this will resolve your issue.

Comment: I did a test similar to Alex's and it looks your code works properly. I would carefully check the code execution step by step and check the values taken by firstRow, secondRow, lastRow and lastRowToShow. Probably your answer is there.

Comment: @Michele Thanks for your comments. It should work in PO sample upon the clarification pertinent to that "magic numbers" I've mentioned (what exactly those variables hold in by-step execution). Best regards,

Comment: @AlexBell This is precisely why I'm so confused. I use the same bit of code in some other workbooks and it works fine. We use a version control system here at work and this code runs perfectly on an older version. I can't fathom what could be causing the issue now.

Comment: @Michele I have indeed tried to isolate my issue. Even `Range("A25:A1623").EntireRows.Hidden` (see second bullet point in my original post) causes the code to stop executing. Very frustrating problem!

Comment: As I stated it in my answer, check for the issue with maxNumberOfRows (where it's declared and what is the value) and also the value of firstRow = thisSheet.Range("mass1").Row. The problem most likely is in one of these issues. Btw, the "older version" may have  maxNumberOfRows  declared as a Global var, and so on. Best regards,

Comment: @BGeorge In my Mac your code revised in a similar way of Alex's works perfectly... By the way if you can only hide, I wonder if `Range(""A" + CStr(lastRowToShow + 1) + ":A" + CStr(lastRow)).EntireRow.Hidden = True` could be a good workaround.

Comment: @Michele Thanks for the efforts, that is indeed a good workaround! @PeterT solved my issue in a comment above - turns out I needed to turn off `ScreenUpdating` before performing the hide and unhide actions.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are from C#/Java side - using `+` to concatenate strings, in VBA, use ampersand `&`.

Assuming `maxNumberOfRows` is a global variable or a function, try below.

```
Private Sub HideUnneededRows(numberToShow As Integer)
    Dim firstRow As Long, secondRow As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long, lastRowToShow As Long
    Dim lCalcMode As Long

    firstRow = ThisWorkbook.Names("mass1").RefersToRange.Row
    secondRow = firstRow + 1
    lastRow = firstRow - 1 + maxNumberOfRows
    lastRowToShow = firstRow - 1 + numberToShow '//numberToShow is usually 200

    lCalcMode = Application.Calculation
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Rows(secondRow & ":" & lastRow).Hidden = True
    Rows(secondRow & ":" & lastRowToShow).Hidden = False
    Application.Calculation = lCalcMode
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Changed rows related data type to `Long` (saving Excel do conversion).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Guilty as charged I am from the C# side. Good to know about the ampersand! 
For my educational benefit, why change the data type to `Long` from `Integer`? I almost exclusively use `Integer` in all of my code, so it would be good to know.

Comment: Another tip for checking out Data Type name - in immediate window, use `?TypeName()` to find the name of the data type (helpful if not Variant). e.g. `?TypeName(Range("A1").Row)`

Comment: Range("A" + CStr(secondRow) + ":A" + CStr(lastRow)) will work just fine in modern Excel VBA. Best regards,

Comment: @AlexBell, yes it works just fine, but reading the code by human is another thing. Using `&` saves manual calls for `CStr`, more efficient. Letting people know a more efficient way is a virtue.

Comment: OK, fine (!=problem :)). Best regards,